# why is empty while loop using more cpu?

Tags: c++, cpu

I have two programs that are supposed to do the same thing with slight differences. Both have infinite game loops that runs forever unless user stops the game somehow. One of these programs' game loop is implemented and rendering something, the other game loop is empty and does nothing(just listens for user to stop).

When i opened the task manager to see resource usage, i have discovered that the program with the empty loop uses 14% CPU and the program that actually draws something to screen uses about 1-2%.

My guess on the subject is as follows:

I compared the code of the both programs and looked for differences and there was not much. Then it occurred to me that the loop that renders to screen might be bound by other factors(like sending pixels to the screen, refresh rate maybe?) So after CPU does its thing, it puts that thread to sleep until other stuff is completed. But since other program does pretty much nothing and doing nothing is really easy, CPU never puts that thread to sleep and just keeps going. I lack the knowledge to confirm that if this is the reason, so i am asking you. Is this the reason this is happening? (Bonus question) And if so, why does the CPU stop at about 14% and not going all the way up to 100% ?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe empty loop has no delay interval and this with drawing something got?

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say for certain without seeing the code, but drawing to the screen will, inevitably involve some wait on IO; how much depends on many factors including sync + buffering options.

As for the 14% cpu usage - I'm guessing that your machine has 8 processing units (either cores or cores * hyperthreading) and your code is singlethreaded - i.e. it is maxing out one processing unit.

Comment: `100 / 8 == 12.5`. I think 14% is coincidental and is the program "idling"

Comment: Windows (I'm assuming windows since the task manager reference) has in my experience been really bad at getting these calculations right.
Also, there is probably some form of wrapper layer in use here (SDL,directx,etc); that is probably correctly yielding and running on a separate instance, which could easily account for an extra percentage.

Comment: Possibly, you're right. There are far too many unknown factors to consider to give a definite answer though, although 12.5% program and 1.5% system idle makes some sense

Comment: I think you are right with the 8 processing units part. And for the other part, i put a `Sleep(150)` call in the empty loop and CPU usage went down to 0.1-1%. So now, i am more convinced that the cause of this is, rendering loop sleeps while IO or some other operations and the empty one doesn't. Of course, there is always the possibility that my computer is trying to teach me a life lesson "Sometimes doing nothing costs more than doing something" :) Thank you for your time.

Comment: Also keep in mind that API references don't give you the entire story on what a call does.  "rendering" will cause all sorts of calls to be made and as you've learned here, some of those *will* be various forms of sleeps/waits that you have little or no control over.